# Swagger and JSON Patch

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following object structure in my database

```
{
    partnerName: '24 Fitness',
    supportedProducts: [
        'FitBit',
        'Protein Powder'
    ]
},
```

where the key value **supportedProducts** can be modified from the client side.

I am constructing a PATCH API method using swagger documentation to support the above functionality. But I am unsure of the patch object definition, as documentation doesn't provide an detailed example of constructing a PATCH.

The current definition that I have ends up in error upon execution and looks like as following

```
 "patch":{
    "description":"Update supported products for a partner",
    "operationId":"Update supported products",
    "parameters":[
      {
        "name": "partnerName",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "supportedProducts",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema":{
          "$ref":"#/definitions/PatchRequest"
        }
      }
    ],
    "responses":{
      "200":{
        "description": "product updated"
      },
      "404":{
        "description": "Not Found"
      }
    }

  "definitions": {
    "PatchRequest":{
      "type": "object",
      "required":[
        "partnerName",
        "supportedProducts"
      ],
      "properties":{
        "partnerName":{"type": "string"},
        "supportedProducts":{
          "type": "array",
          "items":{"type": "string"}
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: What request URL and body does your server expect?

Comment: @Helen request URL is /data/{partnerName} and body should expect the partnerName and supportedProducts as the value. But in my case this fails when i try to configure the above json, way before i can run the server and make requests

Comment: Is this your entire JSON definition or just extracts of it? (Asking because this code alone is not a valid JSON.)

Comment: @Helen this is just a piece of it not the entire json, just the part that i have for patch

Answer (score 14):

For this simple case, I would use a [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) object to describe the operations to make on the target. 
Here is an [example](https://aaronsaray.com/2016/using-json-patch-in-swagger) of a JSON Patch Swagger API.

```
paths:
  /users/{GUID}:
    patch:
      summary: Update a user
      parameters:
        - name: GUID
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
          format: GUID
          description: The GUID of a specific user 
        - name: JsonPatch
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/PatchRequest"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
definitions:
  PatchRequest:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "#/definitions/PatchDocument"
  PatchDocument: 
    description: A JSONPatch document as defined by RFC 6902 
    required:
     - "op"
     - "path"
    properties: 
     op: 
      type: string 
      description: The operation to be performed 
      enum:
       - "add"
       - "remove"
       - "replace"
       - "move"
       - "copy"
       - "test"
     path: 
      type: string 
      description: A JSON-Pointer 
     value: 
      type: object 
      description: The value to be used within the operations.
     from: 
      type: string 
      description: A string containing a JSON Pointer value.
```

Answer (score 9):

For OpenApi 3.0.x the structure of the .yaml file has changed. A valid definition could look like:

```
components:
  requestBodies:
    PatchBody:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PatchBody'

  schemas:
    PatchBody:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/PatchDocument"

    PatchDocument:
      type: object
      description: A JSONPatch document as defined by RFC 6902 
      required:
       - "op"
       - "path"
      properties: 
       op: 
        type: string 
        description: The operation to be performed 
        enum:
         - "add"
         - "remove"
         - "replace"
         - "move"
         - "copy"
         - "test"
       path: 
        type: string 
        description: A JSON-Pointer 
       value: 
        type: object 
        description: The value to be used within the operations.
       from: 
        type: string 
        description: A string containing a JSON Pointer value.            

    patch:
      parameters:
        - $ref:  '#/components/parameters/objectId'
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/PatchBody'
      responses:
        ...
```

Comment: how would you enforce the subcomponent types of the patch value?
for example, let's say your path is /users/dj29_some_user_id_fn32ifn3/address and the object in the value is an Address type component?

Answer (score 2):

Since the JSON Patch format is well defined by RFC 6902 I think it would be sufficient (at least for OpenAPI 3) to specify the content type defined in the RFC, and since it seems to be necessary to define either a schema or example (at least in my swagger editor), to also specify type: string and format: JSON Patch or format: RFC 6902.

It doesn't make sense to redefine a format that is already well defined by the RFC.

Example:

```
paths:
  /users/{GUID}:
    patch:
      summary: Update a user
      parameters:
      - name: GUID
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
        format: GUID
        description: The GUID of a specific user 
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json-patch+json:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: RFC 6902
```