# Providing schema for Django Rest Framework patch request in Swagger

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, yaml, swagger, patch

I'm very new to DRF, Swagger and API in general and I am trying to figure out the patch request.

I have this model:

```
class Object(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    object_type = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    object_code = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    meta = models.JSONField(default=meta_default_value)
    data = models.JSONField(null=True)
    project_id = models.UUIDField(default=None, null=True)
    account_id = models.UUIDField(default=None, null=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=None, null=True)
    object_item = models.UUIDField(default=None, null=True, db_index=True)
```

A serializer:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ['id', 'object_type', 'name', 'object_code', 'created_date',
                  'modified_date', 'meta', 'data', 'project_id', 'account_id',
                  'user_id', 'object_item',]
```

A view:

```
class ObjectViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

The patch definition I have in Swagger is:

```
    patch:
      summary: Updates an existing object with the specified UUID.
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              example: {"name": "Vlad"}
```

It works, but it doesn't provide any schema like I have for post request for example, which inherits it's schema from Object model [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vvoC.png). Is there a way to describe it without referring to my Object model? Because if I do that, clicking Execute will overwrite everything on the model with example values. Do I even need to provide schema for patch?

I read this topic: [Swagger and JSON Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001993/swagger-and-json-patch)
And this resource: https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/05/29/openapi-json-patch/
But I can't seem to figure out how to apply those.

Thank you for your time!